# Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are bounded from above. Show that $A\cup B$ and $A + B$ are also bounded from above.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are bounded from above. Show that $A\cup B$ and $A + B$ are also bounded from above.

My answer trying: Since $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are bounded from above $a\leq x$ and $b\leq y$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$. We will show that $A\cup B$ is bounded from above.

Take $A\cup B=${$a+b\leq x+y:$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$ }
Hence, $A\cup B$ is bounded from above.

**Can you check my answer?** **Can you check my gramer, proof-writing? And, can you explain tahat what is  the $A+B$?**

Comment: What you wrote describes $A+B$, not the union.  the union is just the list of the elements in either or both sets. Also you write $a≤b$ when I think you meant $a≤x$.

Comment: Well, it works for $A+B$.  Hint:  the union is even easier.

Comment: @lulu Thanks.Then, my answer is false.

Comment: Crossed messages.  Your answer works fine for $A+B$.  That is, if $x$ is an upper bound for $A$ and $y$ is an upper bound for $B$, then $x+y$ is an upper bound for $A+B$.  Like I say, the union is even simpler.

Comment: The idea is okay. If $a\leq x$ for each $a\in A$ and $b\leq y$ for each $b\in B$ then $c\leq x+y$ for each $c\in A+B$, since we can find $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with $c=a+b\leq x+y$. For $A\cup B$ you can use $\max(x,y)$ and do likewise.